# How to improve my workflow (git, symfony, composer, bower, grunt)?

Tags: git, deployment, workflows, versioning, symfony

It's time to **improve my workflow**. I never had the responsibility of setting up the infrastructure, managing git, versions or releases. For me it was simple push/pull most of the time and I think, the workflow wasn't state of the art. I'd like to change it and as there are so many ways, I'd like you to help me, finding a good one.

I read about good solutions here and there (e.g. Docker), but I'm a bit lost due to the variety. I'm interested in something stable, smart, simple.

I'm handling the **versioning** (`git tags`) manually; Example: Version 1.2.3 *(1 = major release [huge changes], 2 = minor release [features], 3 = patch level [bug fixes])*. I'm not using **build numbers**. Should I, why? I can't see the advantage as long as working alone or in a small team on private code.

**Environments**:

- Development (dev): local
- Testing (test): online
- Production (prod): online

When I've a new version or testable commit, I install it on the test environment; as soon as it's declared as stable, I do the same for prod.

I use **bower** (dependencies) and **grunt** (tasks) for the frontend-development, but run it only in the `dev`-environment.

**Workflow for a normal project**:

1. `init` external `git` repository
2. `clone` empty `git` repository locally
3. Install packages *(Symfony, etc.)* via **Composer**
4. Configure packages (`config.yml`)
5. Create local `parameters.yml`
6. Development (dev)
7. Cloning (test/prod)
8. Create `parameters.yml` for test/prod
9. `composer install` / `composer update`
10. Possibly running some scripts `php bin/console ...`

**Problem**: I configure (4) the installed packages (3) locally, but I don't push the `vendor`-directory. When installing the packages (8, `composer.json`), I'll get errors, because the `config.yml` has configurations for yet not-installed packages.

My current solution is to upload the `vendor`-directory manually for the first installation, to avoid this conflict. I don't like the solution. How to improve my workflow?

Comment: You seem to know about this, but I'm adding it nonetheless: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 2):

For the config.yml, an environment variable would be a more modern setup:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    vendor: '%env(VENDOR)%'
```

Having a second yaml file with a default directory would avoid the error:

```
# config/default.yaml
parameters:
    env(VENDOR): '/mnt'
```

**References**

- [How to Set external Parameters in the Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html)
- [The /mnt directory definition by The Linux Information Project](http://www.linfo.org/mnt.html)
- [symfony-EnvParamsBuilderBundle: create parameters.yml file based on environment variables.](https://github.com/PiwikPRO/symfony-EnvParamsBuilderBundle)
- [composer-environment-injector](https://github.com/tburschka/composer-environment-injector)
- [Twig Template Engine for Magento2](https://github.com/SchumacherFM/Magento2-Twig)